# How to configure multiple virtual applications in Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, iis, azure-web-app-service, web-config

I'm creating an API using Express and trying to deploy on Azure App Service. I've managed to deployed and run it successfully on the default path `site\wwwroot`.

It works fine but I want to deploy it on a different path `site\backend`. So I've setup the path mapping for it and deployed the exact same code and it gives out an error.

I've deletes the code in the `site\wwwroot`, thinking it may be because of the `web.config` duplication and same result. I also restarted the App Service and still not working.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

#### Error

[image: Azure App Service - Page Isn't Working Error 500]

#### Path Mapping

[image: Azure App Services Path Mapping]

#### Application Setting

```
SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true
WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION=~16
```

#### Web Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     This configuration file is required if iisnode is used to run node processes behind
     IIS or IIS Express.  For more information, visit:

     https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config
-->

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- Visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx for more information on WebSocket support -->
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{PATH_INFO}"/>
        </rule>

        <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    
    <!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

    <!--
      You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options:
        * watchedFiles: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched for changes to restart the server
        * node_env: will be propagated to node as NODE_ENV environment variable
        * debuggingEnabled - controls whether the built-in debugger is enabled

      See https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config for a full list of options
    -->
    <!--<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>-->
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am able to deploy multiple Apps under Site folder in Azure App Service.
Please follow the below steps.

- In Azure Portal create an App Service with the Runtime stack Node.
- By default virtual path with `/` with Physical path `site\wwwroot` will be created.
- In VS, Create 2 New Express App and Name it as `Exp1`  and `Exp2`.
- In Azure Portal, add new `Virtual Directories` with name `Exp1`  and `Exp2`.
  [image]
- Make sure the App name and the Virtual path name are same.
- In Azure App Service => Overview, you will find an option to `download Publish Profile` (Get publish profile).
  [image]
- In VS, Right Click on the Project folder (Exp1) which you want to Deploy and select `Import Profile` . In Browse option select the downloaded `Publish Profile` and Continue the next steps.
  [image]

In Publish Connection settings, change the Sitename as below Save and Publish.
[image]

Repeat the same steps with App 2 (Exp2).
You can see the Folders `Exp1` and `Exp2` with source files are created and `wwwroot` folder exists as well.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can follow below steps:

- place the backend folder inside the "site"
- open app service configuration
- select path mapping-> + add new virtual directory or application
- give name and path as shown below:

[image]

save the changes and try to access your API as https://domain/test/api/etc

Answer (score 0):

why would you configure multiple virtual machines in Azure while you can create a blueprint or a function and use it, something that looks like horizontal scaling configure once build many.

hope this helps :)